# How can we match tagname from two state variables and display the data of the clicked item alone in react page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On click on child level plus icon, how can we match `tagname` from two state variables and display the data of the clicked item only in react page. Right now I am filtering
data based on `id`, but the data in displayed multiple time as per screen shot. Could someone please advise here on how can i resolve it ?

CSB link added
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-lake-g3s2q6?file=/src/App.js:0-3032

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    count: 10,
    tagname: "react"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    count: 3,
    tagname: "unix"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    count: 5,
    tagname: "cypress"
  }
];

const detailsTag = [
  {
    id: 1,
    tagname: "react",
    blogdetails: "React State "
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tagname: "unix",
    blogdetails: "Unix commands"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tagname: "cypress",
    blogdetails: "Cypress request command"
  }
];

const GroupByTags = () => {
  const [groupTags, setGroupTags] = useState(data);
  const [detailsTags, setDetailsTags] = useState(detailsTag);
  const [filterTags, setFilterTags] = useState([]);
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  const [isShownFullDetails, setShowFullDetails] = useState(false);

  const style = {
    width: "30px",
    height: "30px",
    marginLeft: "20px",
    backgroundColor: "#dae0f5",
    fontWeight: "900",
    opacity: 1,
    borderColor: "#fafcff"
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setIsShown((current) => !current);
  };

  const showFullDetails = (idx) => {
    const filterdata = detailsTags.filter((item) => item?.id === idx);
    setShowFullDetails((current) => !current);
    setFilterTags(filterdata);
  };

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="groupbyTags">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="plusBtn">
            <input
              onClick={handleClick}
              style={style}
              type="button"
              value="+"
            ></input>
          </div>
          {isShown && (
            <div className="groupByTagData">
              {groupTags.map(({ id, count, tagname }) => (
                <div key={id} className="row">
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <input
                      onClick={() => showFullDetails(id)}
                      style={style}
                      type="button"
                      value="+"
                    ></input>
                  </div>{" "}
                  <br></br>
                  {isShownFullDetails && (
                    <div className="groupByTagData">
                      {filterTags.map(({ id, tagname, blogdetails }) => (
                        <div key={id} className="row">
                          <div className="groupByTagDetails">
                            <div className="groupByTagName">{blogdetails}</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <span className="groupByTagCount">{count}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <span className="groupByTagName">{tagname}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GroupByTags;
```

Issue here `React State` is displayed multiple time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
const showFullDetails = (idx) => {
    const filterdata = detailsTags.filter((item) => item?.id === idx);
    setShowFullDetails((prev) => (prev === idx ? false : idx));
    setFilterTags(filterdata);
};
....
{
    isShownFullDetails === id && (
        <div className="groupByTagData">
            {filterTags.map(({ id, tagname, blogdetails }) => (
                <div key={id} className="row">
                    <div className="groupByTagDetails">
                        <div className="groupByTagName">{blogdetails}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-haze-6mhe1o)

Comment: Thank you very much, upvoted now, Can you please explain this line >> `setShowFullDetails((prev) => (prev === idx ? false : idx));`

Comment: @soccerway if the id of clicked input equal current display tagname, it will set isShownFullDetails to false. If it not equal, i will set isShownFullDetails to the id of clicked input

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should change the way you map the array:

```
{isShown && (
            <div className="groupByTagData">
              {groupTags.map((e) => (
                <div key={e.id} className="row">
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <input
                      onClick={() => showFullDetails(e.id)}
                      style={style}
                      type="button"
                      value="+"
                    ></input>
                  </div>{" "}
                  <br></br>
                  {isShownFullDetails && (
                    <div className="groupByTagData">
                      {filterTags.map((j) => (
                        <div key={j.id} className="row">
                          <div className="groupByTagDetails">
                            <div className="groupByTagName">{j.blogdetails}</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ))}
                    </div>
                  )}
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <span className="groupByTagCount">{e.count}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="groupByTagInfo">
                    <span className="groupByTagName">{e.tagname}</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
```

Try this way of mapping

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried but still getting same values repeated